# Compare data (two cells) every week automatically in Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using Google Sheet to manipulate data. I would like to automate one of my tasks.
Every Monday I check if my data has increased or decreased, for that I use a file that updates my data every week in a different row.
I would like to compare the last week with the one before. Basically, I would like to run a script that understands to compare one cell with the one right before so that I don't have to do it manually every week.

How can I do this with Google App Script ?

Thank you for your help!

Natacha

Comment: Is the data numerical.  What should the comparison function accomplish?  What kind of answer do you want?  We are not inside your head only you are hopefully?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a [Time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) to run once a week.

To compare one cell contents with another, you can use the [`getValue()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue) method of the `Range` class:

```
const range1 = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue() // for example
const range2 = sheet.getRange("A2").getValue()

if (range1 < range2) {

}
else if (range1 > range2) {

}
// etc
```